# Сохранить результат запроса из MySQL в Excel файл

Tags: mysql, python, sql, excel

Как сделать чтоб эта строчка не выводила данные, а сохраняла их в `xlsx`. Хоть убей сообразить не могу.

```
print ("cursor.description: ", cursor.description)
print()
for row in cursor:
  print (row)
```

---

Надо сохранить в таблицу данные с базы не могу сообразить как

```
import pymysql.cursors
import xlwt


connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',db='test',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

print ("Подключено!!!")

try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sql="SELECT prod_name,prod_price From products"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                print ("cursor.description: ", cursor.description)
                print()
                for row in cursor:
                                 print (row)


finally:
 connection.close()
```

Comment: Вы можете пояснить что вы хотите сделать в этой строке: `print ("cursor.description: ", cursor.description)`?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы сохранить результат SQL запроса в Excel файл удобно будет воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

conn = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@mysql_host/mysql_db')

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ...", conn)
df.to_excel(r'/path/to/result.xlsx', index=False)
```